# Passing URL parameters to JS with Jinja

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

After searching a simple solution to the question of passing url parameters in a Flask template in JS using Jinja and reading many replies on server-side and client-side, I decided to use this one terrible hack that surprisingly works!

```
    <select id="project_select" onchange="
    var d = document.getElementById('project_select').value;
    location.href ='{{ url_for("display_project", p = "any_string") }}'.replace('any_string', d);">
```

I don't care why it works at this stage. What I would kindly ask SO users is whether there is indeed no better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer not to mix template language and Javascript.

I'd rather put it inside a `<input type="hidden" value="{{url_for(...)}}>` and then read its value via JS.